# apksigner fails when using openssl certificates directly with cordova apk

Tags: android, cordova, apk, android-signing

TLDR: `apksigner sign -key rsa_der.key -cert x509.cert app.apk` fails when directly using a certificate and key generated by `openssl` which are not stored in a keystore.

---

I am wanting to get apksigner working for use on our CI server, however, I'd prefer not to generate a java keystore file on each build, or store one securely between builds.

The app is a cordova app, built with `cordova build android --release`.

I did the following to create a certificate and key in the expected formats. I have tried a variety of ways of generating the certificate and key, the following is the most terse. (nb. passphrase.txt contains a large password, all commands executed on a Fedora 29 machine)

```bash
$ openssl req -x509 -days 9125 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout rsa_pem.key -out x509.cert # generate certificate & key
$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in rsa_pem.key -out rsa_der.key -passout file:passphrase.txt # convert key over to DER formatted pkcs8, as required by apksigner
```

Attempting to use the certificate and key to sign an apk fails:

```bash
$ apksigner sign -key rsa_der.key --key-pass file:passphrase.txt -cert x509.cert app.apk
Failed to load signer "signer #1"
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Failed to load PKCS #8 encoded private key from ./rsa_der.key
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromFiles(ApkSignerTool.java:911)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCerts(ApkSignerTool.java:665)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.access$500(ApkSignerTool.java:615)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:269)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:89)
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Not an RSA, EC, or DSA private key
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPkcs8EncodedPrivateKey(ApkSignerTool.java:968)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromFiles(ApkSignerTool.java:909)
    ... 4 more
```

As stated above, I'd prefer to not create and delete a keystore on every build, or need to store it between builds.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The steps you provided are correct, I can successfully sign a apk on my macOS by using 28.0.3 apksigner.

Comment: I don't know about apksigner, but jarsigner does work with a pkcs12 keystore which can be created with `openssl pkcs12` from key.pem and cert.pem (Or even `keytool` can be used to convert pkcs12 into jks. All these steps can be performed within a script without human interaction.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, it ended up being the key length (I *think*), and using a file based passphrase.

The following worked for us:

```
openssl req -x509 -days 9125 -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out certificate_x509.pem
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform DER -in key.pem -inform PEM -out key.pk8 -nocrypt
apksigner sign --key key.pk8 --cert certificate_x509.pem app.apk
```

As this lacks a passphrase on the private key it is somewhat less secure.

Comment: An RSA key with 1024 bits is pretty short. I am not sure but for new apps (not updates) Google may refuse the app because of the short key length.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on both this problem and this answer, and found a workaround which allows use of an RSA key size of >2048 bits. I'm not x509v3 savvy, but here's what I found.

When you use `openssl` to generate a self signed certificate with an RSA key, it always inserts an x509v3 extension claiming that the cert is for a CA use case:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey RSA:2048 -keyout rsa-2048.key -out rsa-2048.pem -sha256 -nodes -subj "/CN=test"
...
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in rsa-2048.pem | grep -A 6 "X509v3 extensions:"
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                E9:E6:99:7F:38:F4:5A:98:96:56:8C:DA:36:EC:17:AF:58:45:3E:31
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                E9:E6:99:7F:38:F4:5A:98:96:56:8C:DA:36:EC:17:AF:58:45:3E:31
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
```

For some reason, `apksigner.jar` doesn't care about the `CA` extension when the key size is 2048 or lower. But above that, it rejects the key. (I'd guess that they tightened the spec when they added support for larger key sizes, but that's just a guess.)

You can munge the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` file to not insert the extension, but I was looking for something simpler that could be copy/pasted as needed. I came up with just adding a different, explicit x509v3 extension when generating the key, and everything works (at least for now, ymmv):

```
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey RSA:8096 -keyout rsa-8096.key -out rsa-8096.pem -sha256 -nodes -subj "/CN=test 8096" -extensions "usr_cert"
...
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in rsa-8096.pem | grep -A 6 "X509v3 extensions:"
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                75:AA:A8:74:D4:3C:D9:3E:33:3F:C1:F1:AB:B9:BF:19:AD:B3:DC:C5
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                DirName:/CN=test 8096
$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform der -nocrypt -in rsa-8096.key -out rsa-8096.pkcs8
$ java -jar /usr/share/java/apksigner.jar sign -key rsa-8096.pkcs8 -cert rsa-8096.pem aligned-two-files.apk
$ java -jar /usr/share/java/apksigner.jar verify aligned-two-files.apk
```